# Command `open` not working on Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: command-line

I am trying to follow [Introduction to bash for data analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMaFdfIlK58&feature=emb_title). It has a line of commands as: `open ~/.bash_profile`.

The tutorial is on Mac computers, but on the comments section it says that I can also do it on Ubuntu through VirtualBox

But this command is not recognized on Ubuntu:

[image: the command 'Open' not working on Ubuntu Terminal]

Is there any alternative on Ubuntu that I can use instead of `open` command?

Comment: Without context of what the command is trying to do, I'd guess you could replace "open" with "Use your favorite text editor".

Comment: She responds to this question in the comments section, she intends you to just use whatever text editor you want.

Comment: Another difference, due to how terminals behave and what per-user files exist by default: in Ubuntu you should rarely do anything with `~/.bash_profile`. Only *login shells* (on either OS) use it. In macOS, Terminal.app runs bash as a login shell; GUI terminals in Ubuntu and other GNU/Linux systems do not. Also, Ubuntu doesn't already have `~/.bash_profile`. If you create it, bash uses it *instead* of `~/.profile`, which in Ubuntu has nontrivial contents you probably want run. In Ubuntu, commands you want every interactive bash shell to run should go at the end of `~/.bashrc` as vanadium says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `gedit` instead. I believe what you're trying to do is opening the file in a text editor.

Answer (score 9):

In linux, `xdg-open` will open a file with the associated application.

```
xdg-open ~/.bashrc
```

will open the configuration file `.bashrc` located in your home folder (represented here by the shortcut notation `~/` with your default text editor.

Answer (score 1):

From `man open` on macos:

```
The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had
double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the
default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the
specified files.
```

So what that commend is doing is just opening the file in whatever the default editor is. Since `~/bash_profile` is a plain text config file, you can open it directly using whatever text editor you prefer (e.g. `gedit ~/bash_profile` , `nano ~/bash_profile`, etc.).

There are also a few options for opening with an automatic default editor

- `xdg-open`
- `gnome-open`

My personal preference is to be more intentional with what programs I'm using. However you can try out those options and see what works, and what works best for you.